# Query that returns rows that start with numeric values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-like

i tried to write a query that returns rows that start with numeric values in Oracle.

for example, if the values are "123abc", "abc123", "123abc123", "1a", "a1"

it will returns: "123abc", "123abc123", "1a"

i tried this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE regexp_like(column_Name,'[^0-9](*)')
```

where is my mistake?

Comment: and is that not the correct result? it is doing what you expect it to

Comment: the results that i wont, not what i got.
right now its returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i guess you are looking for this regex:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE regexp_like(column_Name,'^[0-9]')
```

or in short

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE regexp_like(column_Name,'^\d')
```

What you did is negate the result of the elements in the bracket, the `^` needs to be before the brackets